# Invisible indicator addTA Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

When I try to display an indicator on weekly data using Quantmod's addTA function the indicator is invisible.  Below is a toy example:

```
require(quantmod)

ticker <- c("^GSPC")
getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("1960-01-04")) 

#change to weeklies 
spy <- to.weekly(GSPC)

spyAD <- Ad(spy)

spyDVI <- DVI(spyAD)[,3]

chartSeries(GSPC,theme = chartTheme('white'), TA = NULL, subset = "1995-08::")

addTA(spyDVI)
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?  It works perfectly on daily data, but not only weekly or monthly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine on weekly and monthly data if your `chartSeries` call uses data of the same frequency.  Your example plots daily data, then calls `addTA` on weekly data.

For example:

```
chartSeries(spy, theme=chartTheme('white'), TA=NULL, subset="1995-08::") 
addTA(spyDVI)
```

The lesson is that you have to be very careful if you call `addTA` with different data than what is supplied to the original `chartSeries` call.